# Does Installer built in VS 2008 work in VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I am working on an old project that I can see it is originally written in 2009, and I have opened it in `VS 2010` and can modify code and compile, etc but they also have some Installer project and that gives me error of `'PostBuildEvent' failed with error code '1' 'Unspecified error'`
So I was wondering is it because I am on `VS 2010` and it should be `VS 2008`? or there are other problems and it should have worked in VS2010 too? and what are the things I can do to solve this issue?

Comment: Well, have you looked at your post build events?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, there was nothing there. Empty.

Answer (score 0):

It does work with VS2010.  Issue was that there was a missing JS file that was helping installer with Windows Vista, once we found and added that, it compiled fine.